# what are the Best practice to store or monitor UI logs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, webservice-client

what are the best practices to store the ui logs/error statements of all the clients in the server side,
so that we can analyse this later

Answer (score 1):

Sqlite or Index DB can be used to store client errors which can later be pushed to server side